# Javamail java.lang.IllegalStateException: Folder is not Open

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to crawl an hotmail pop3 account which has about 4000+ messages. 
The problem is I couldn't download the whole email due to an exception that occurs at non-specific time at the following function :

```
recipients = message.getRecipients(type);
```

The exception is :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Folder is not Open
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.checkOpen(POP3Folder.java:539)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.getProtocol(POP3Folder.java:569)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.loadHeaders(POP3Message.java:542)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Message.getHeader(POP3Message.java:336)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:700)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getRecipients(MimeMessage.java:534)
    at edu.coeia.onlinemail.OnlineEmailDownloader.getAddress(OnlineEmailDownloader.java:568)
```

Comment: Take a look at -> http://osdir.com/ml/java.classpath.extensions.javamail/2004-07/msg00006.html same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you closed the folder before accessing the content of the message.
If you want to access the message content after closing the folder, you need to
make a local copy of the message, either in memory or on disk.

Comment: I didn't close the folder. Did the server close the folder itself?

Comment: Possibly.  If the connection was left idle too long, the server might close it.